# Disable stylish on certain sites in firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I use dark theme in the Firefox, however sometimes I visit several sites that don't need such theme. I want to see them in original style.

I found the way to enable specific features per site with :

```
@-moz-document domain("google.com")
```

Is there a way to disable stylish at all *only for* certain domains without annoying mouse clicking to disable the whole stylish for all aites and enable it again after?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not as easy as one would like. The [relevant bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=349813) hasn't been fixed as of now. You can achieve the same effect using the [`regexp()` condition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@document#Syntax) (available since Firefox 6) but the regular expressions required are rather ugly. E.g. to exclude `google.com` domain you would write:

```
@-moz-document regexp("https?://(?!([^.]+\\.)?google\\.com[/:]).*")
```

If you need to specify multiple domains you have to do it like this:

```
@-moz-document regexp("https?://(?!([^.]+\\.)?(google\\.com|example\\.com|foo\\.bar)[/:]).*")
```